# Rootless VS Code (dockerized)?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, rootless, code-server, vscodium

Is there any method to install VS Code in a docker container as a web-based editor that can be run in a rootless mode (no `sudo` in container entrypoint scripts etc.)?

E.g. to run it in this scenario:

`docker run -u 12345 --cap-drop=all repo/rootless-vscode`

Comment: Added specific details and test, reduced to just one method to avoid opinion poll to address the closing voters concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be done with [code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server).
Note that it needs root permissions to install the server, but runs it as `newuser`.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y sudo curl

RUN curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser

USER newuser

CMD [ "code-server", "--bind-addr", "0.0.0.0:8080" ]
```

For a more complete example, check out their code-server [CI release Dockerfile](https://github.com/coder/code-server/blob/5276e41606c89c3e9d55e87c2995d4c7be02f74d/ci/release-image/Dockerfile).

Comment: Very concise! Would be nice if it worked without root though (see test...)

Comment: @mirekphd Do you mean running Docker without root on your host? Are you able to run any other docker container without root?

Comment: Hi, I meant: running containerized apps without any extra capabilities ("rootless") and with a random user ID assigned at runtime - this is the reality of many corporate clusters (Openshift / OKD / hardened k8s) (see test from my question)